# Python - one of my txt files opens without the full path, other doesn't

Tags: python

I have two files in my directory, a.txt and b.txt - when I run this on one of the files (a.txt), it opens fine,

```
my_list = []

with open('a.txt','r') as f:
    my_list = f.readlines()
```

however, when I run the same on b.txt I get the following,
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'b.txt'`

but I know for certain the files are both there. Also, when I check with `file` in terminal, both are `ASCII text` files.

Comment: Do you have read privileges for file B?

Comment: are you sure that the `b.txt` is in the correctly directory?

Comment: In addition to privileges, what else is different about `b.txt` _qua_ `a.txt`? Length, content, encoding …? Maybe show us `ls -lF`

Comment: can you send the result of `ls your/script/dir` or `dir y:\our\script\dir` if on windows ?

Comment: This is the output of the working file `-rw-r--r--@ 1 freddyvenegas  staff    17 May 14 15:36 a.txt` this is the non-working file `-rw-r--r--  1 freddyvenegas  staff    84 May 16 12:29 b.txt` - I see the difference, the `@` what exactly is that and is that what is causing the issue?